# SQL Scheduling Query which results in 5 scheduling slots per day for a given week, regardless if there's job to assign to those slots

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query that reads our Jobs table and produces a schedule for each day of a given week. I want the results to show all 5 starting slots, regardless if there are jobs actually assigned to those slots.
Example: Week of 03-24 thru 03-30

```
Mon - 03/25 - 01 - Job# 123456
Mon - 03/25 - 02 - Job# 123457  
Mon - 03/25 - 03 - Job# 123458
Mon - 03/25 - 04 - Empty
Mon - 03/25 - 05 - Empty
Tue - 03/26 - 01 - Job# 123459
Tue - 03/26 - 02 - Job# 123460
Tue - 03/26 - 03 - Job# 123461
Tue - 03/26 - 03 - Job# 123462
Tue - 03/26 - 04 - Job# 123463
Tue - 03/26 - 05 - Empty
Wed...Fri

select  JobNum, 
        StartDate,
        Line,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Line, StartDate order by Line, StartDate) as 'Slot#'
 from jobs
 where StartDate Between '2024-03-24' And '2024-03-30'
 And Line = 'Line A'

JobNum  StartDate           Line    Slot#
123456  2024-03-25 00:00:00.000 Line A  1
123457  2024-03-25 00:00:00.000 Line A  2
123458  2024-03-25 00:00:00.000 Line A  3 
123459  2024-03-26 00:00:00.000 Line A  1
123460  2024-03-26 00:00:00.000 Line A  2
123461  2024-03-26 00:00:00.000 Line A  3
123462  2024-03-27 00:00:00.000 Line A  1
123463  2024-03-27 00:00:00.000 Line A  2
123464  2024-03-27 00:00:00.000 Line A  3
123465  2024-03-28 00:00:00.000 Line A  1
123466  2024-03-28 00:00:00.000 Line A  2
123467  2024-03-28 00:00:00.000 Line A  3
123468  2024-03-29 00:00:00.000 Line A  1
123469  2024-03-29 00:00:00.000 Line A  2
123470  2024-03-29 00:00:00.000 Line A  3
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a calendar table with holidays identified and slot table with 5 records that you can join to?

Comment: I'm very limited as to what I can create. This query needs to be recreated in an Epicor BAQ.

Comment: Row ``Tue - 03/26 - 03 - Job# 123462``  is doubtful. Maybe ``Wed - 03/27 - 01 - Job# 123462`` ?

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that I duplicated slot# 03. It shouldn't be be there.